# Rails 3.1 Time zone, totally stumped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I have a user model and a friend model.. I'm trying to keep track of when the last time a user contacted a friend was.  I have a daemon that collects this info and saves it with:

```
  friend.last_contact = Time.parse(status.created_at) #this is where I go wrong
  friend.save
```

I'm getting this info from twitter which is reporting in UTC with a format like:

```
"Thu Jan 05 23:29:00 +0000 2012"
```

When I enter the rails console and do these commands, the date is correctly saved as UTC with UTC time.  However, when I collect this info through a daemon, it is saving it in the database with UTC but with the local time.. which makes it 4 hours off..   I'm running my daemon with a rails runner so I believe active support should be fine.  I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong..

From my server rails console some output:

```
1.9.1 :001 > Time.now
=> 2012-01-10 00:40:37 +0400 

1.9.1 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Mon, 09 Jan 2012 20:40:56 UTC +00:00
```

This is a the timestamp saved when a message was retrieved 20 minutes ago:

```
1.9.1 :009 > b.last_contact
 => Tue, 10 Jan 2012 00:27:20 UTC +00:00
```

You'll notice that it's the 'Time.now' of the server.. but saved as UTC... What's messing me up is if i go into the rails console and I type:

```
> friend.last_contact = Time.now ; friend.save
```

or

```
> friend.last_contact = Time.zone.now ; friend.save
```

I come out with the correct time...... any help appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't `friend.last_contact = status.created_at` work?

Comment: Sorry, what you see there was just my last attempt.. status.created_at ends up with the same incorrect utc value in the db..

Comment: I should add i've also tried: friend.last_contact = Time.now in the daemon file as well as friend.last_contact = Time.zone.now and both didn't work either, same misguided utc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this same issue, and from Twitter too (though that's not really relevant).

Three thoughts:

1. Is the server you're running your daemon on in UTC time?  The way time zones work in Rails 3 is that the time is converted to the system time zone *on save* (not before).  So it looks ok, until you persist the value.
2. Is it possible your test/prod DB is not in UTC, but your local test DB is?  If you're running in a hosted datacenter, sometimes they run their DB's not in UTC but in whatever timezone they're hosted in.
3. Is it possible the daemon runs under a user account with a different TZ environment variable (or different locale)?  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: The server is on +4 GMT Moscow time.. which is the offset that I'm wrong.. I thougt that didn't matter, because it was persisted to the DB in UTC anyways?  Should my server be in UTC time?

Comment: Yes, the server will determine the timezone offset when the record is saved.  So there's your problem.  You'll need to either set your server to UTC, or tell Rails to use local time by setting config.time_zone = 'Moscow'. BTW can you please "accept" my answer so I get credit? :-)

Comment: Heh, I wanted to try it first, but I'll accept it now anyways. And post back if it doesn't work. Thank you though! :)